# jquery: appendTo lose stripslashes in a hidden field

Tags: php, jquery, regex, dom, appendto

Am working on a front-end utility for creating forms using PHP and jQuery; i can add several specific fields that later will be used on a form and which parameters are stored in dinamically inserted hidden fields of the graphic interface. Everything is working fine so far but i stumbled in a problem with the code that adds the fields to the display (and that later is parsed to generate the final form data); in the injected DIV that contains the parameters the backslashes of a regex stored in a hidden field are stripped out. Here is part of the code:

```
var fieldsNumber =1; //this determines the field id of the inserted feature
fieldCenterHtml =   '<div class="formFieldCenterArea">'
        +   '<div class="formParamContainer"><label>Default value:</label><input type="text" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_value" value=""/></div>' 
            +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_type" value="phone_number"/>'
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_firstValue" value=""/>'
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_valueList" value=""/>'
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_hasRegex" value="1"/>'
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_regex" value="/^[(]?\d{3}[)]?\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{4}$/"/>' 
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_hasSize" value="0"/>'
        +   '<input type="hidden" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_size" value="0"/>'
    +   '<div class="formParamContainer"><label>is Required:</label><input type="checkbox" name="field_'+fieldsNumber+'_isRequired"  value="1" /></div>';
        +   '</div> <!-- end formCenterField --'+'>';

//the injecting code

fieldDataHtml = fieldCenterHtml;


    //insert the field in the DOM

        var element = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'element',
        html: fieldDataHtml
    }).appendTo('#form-area-container');
```

When the field got inserted in the page, the field_1_regex appear like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="/^[(]?d{3}[)]?s?-?s?d{3}s?-?s?d{4}$/" name="field_1_regex">
```

and loses all the backslashes in the regular expression. 
I suspect appendTo is stripping the backslashes at the insertion in the DOM; how can i go around this problem?

A  [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aANNs/3/) is on jsFiddle.

[EDIT] solved out; i decided to posticipate the population of the regex field pushing the empty field and, after the insertion in the DOM using jquery to isnert the value.

A test of the solution in jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aANNs/3/).

Answer (score 0):

That might be because the backslashes should be escaped in a string like this:

```
'_regex" value="/^[(]?\\d{3}[)]?\\s?-?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?-?\\s?\\d{4}$/"/>'
```